# Access variable from outrside of class

Tags: php, function, class

I have this small question:

Lets say: I have a script to translate my website. It is something more or less like this:

```
//getting browser language
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
if($lang !== 'pt'){
    $lang == 'en';
}
```

than I include one of the several php files that have the translation array:

```
$path = 'languages/';
include_once($path.$lang.'.php');
```

Example of the translate array:

```
//pt.php
$translate = array(
'Hello' => 'Olá',
'World' => 'mundo'
);
```

So, the main idea now is to have a word class that gets this array to translate strings and get the first letter to uppercase. So what I have now:

//class word.php

```
class word {
    public function translate($lang, $string){
        global $translate;
        include('languages/'.$lang.'.php');
        $string = $translate['hello'];
        return $string;
    }

    function uc_sentence($string){
        $string = ucfirst(strtolower($string));
        $string = preg_replace_callback('/[.!?].*?\w/', create_function('$matches', 'return strtoupper($matches[0]);'),$string);
        echo $string;
    }
}
```

So, what happens here?
I can do something like:

```
$word = new word();
$word->translate('pt',$string);
$word->uc_sentence($string);
```

And it will output the translated string. But it seems to me like this is like a really poor coding.

What I had in mind was to make the include_once('pt.php') available to all the functions in the class and afterwards run the translate inside the uc_sentence.

How can I make this happen.

Answer (score 1):

Pass in the array as an argument of the `word` constructor:

```
class word {
    private $words;

    public function __construct(array $words) {
        $this->words = $words;
    }

    // rest of class here
}

// When translating:
$word = new word($translate);
$word->translate('fr', $string);
```

This concept is known as dependency injection, however I would do it like this in case you have more arrays to pass:

```
class word {

    private $words = array();

    public function __construct(array $words) {
        $this->addWords($words);
    }

    public function addWords(array $words) {
        $this->words = array_merge($this->words, $words);
    }

    // rest of class here

}
```

Comment: Plus one for the suggestion. Why not making it `protected` so that the whole family can have fun with `$words`? ;)